# Axios Bearer Token Header

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, post, axios

I am trying to make a post request using axios with a bearer token but I keep receiving Error 401: "Authentication credentials were not provide".

Here is my code for the request below.

It works when I send the request on postman.

```
axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://websiteurl..',
      header: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer asdf123'
      },
      data: {
        "message": "hello"
      }
    })
    .then()
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    })
```

Comment: Did my advice help you?

Answer (score 0):

"headers", not "header" I assume. You have a typo.